# what is webpage advertising impression program

Tags: web-applications, asp.net-2.0, ads

`i want to build it in asp.net 2.0
what actually advertising impression program
means?`

what is this term means like geography, demographics, setting up a rate card.

how can i easily  build it?
 any reference site for example 
any pdf for help

any help will be welcomed

Comment: You want to build something, but you don't know what it is?

Comment: Wikipedia and Google are your friends?

Comment: yes i want to build it but i don't know what it is actually  as i know what ads are but i don't know what is impression program

Comment: An impression is the display of an advert on a page. I.e. If your advert was shown to 5 people, it'd have 5 impressions. If it was clicked once by 3 of those users, it'd have 3 click throughs http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&defl=en&q=define:ad+impressions&sa=X&psj=1&ei=sz6rTNfVHYLl4gaIydjmCA&ved=0CBgQkAE.

Comment: thankzzz for the help i got what is impression ? but what is demographics

Comment: @user404305 - I just told you. Read my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are talking about Affiliate programs, those affiliates provide a bit of html which you can paste in your website. The html consists of text and an image (or a Flash file) which is clickable. After clicking the image it submits some id back.